# IE11 is missing User Agent Style for main element (display: block;)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, user-agent, internet-explorer-11

Apparantly IE11 doesn't have a User Agent Style for `<main>` and therefor no `display: block;` on it. **Why is there no User Agent Style?** Is this a bug or on purpose?

Adding `display: block;` to the main element is enough, tho.

Comment: I suspect it's simply because the `main` element was added to the HTML5 specification a bit too late in IE11's development cycle. Luckily it's an easy fix for you :)

Comment: It'll be needed for older versions of all the other browsers too, so you wouldn't want to hide it behind conditional comments anyway!

Comment: Note that `main` is also inline in the last Safari for Windows (5.1.7) and the last Presto-driven Opera (12.16). And I'm pretty sure it was until fairly recently in Firefox.

Comment: Even if IE was the only browser to do this, there's no reason to do anything IE-specific here anyway. Having that one line of CSS in there won't break anything, so no point making it browser-specific.

Comment: @kleinfreund This applies to all of the elements that're new in HTML5, depending on how far back your browser support goes. [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) gives you a solid foundation on which to work (and you're already using HTML5Shiv).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `main` element is indeed not fully supported by IE11. Adding `main { display: block; }` to your CSS is the best solution for IE9+. You don't need to make conditional comments - since `display: block;` is the default behavior for `main` elements, it won't mess up anything.

Comment: Since `<main>` is about a year old, Firefox, Chrome and Safari (and other webkit browsers) support it since May this year.

Comment: When I changed my `<main>` element to a `<div>` it fixed it which led me to this answer. If only all browsers used the same rendering engine :(

Comment: @NickBedford They wouldn't all need to have the same engine, if they would at least all have good engines (staring at ie/edge)