# CSS - Internet Explorer and the <main> tag background

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I have a pretty simple layout which renders fine in both Firefox and Chrome, but Internet Explorer (version 11) seems to be unable to render any kind of background color for the `<main>` element.

I have the `<main>` element as a child of the `<body>` element and neither `background` or `background-color` seem to make any difference. `<main>` will always have the same background as `<body>`. I haven't found anything that says whether or not this is a bug in IE.

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqkj52u8/2/) using Internet Explorer to see what I mean.

Obviously, I could just replace `<main>` with `<div id="main">` and update my CSS selectors but I want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: [It's actually pretty easy to find the *reason* why this is happening](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

IE11 does not support the `<main>` element natively. You can introduce support for it by either using a script like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie), or a single harmless line of JS:

```
document.createElement('main');
```

The element will not be inserted in the DOM, but it will now be recognized as a proper element by IE. After this, it still does not have proper styling. Add the following to your CSS:

```
main {
    display:block;
}
```

And all will be fine. The reason you currently see it as not getting any content because IE does not add it to the box model without these 2 steps, and as such it gets no 'layout' or 'size'. It's just invisible, that's why you see the body. It **does** contain elements, which get rendered (sort of) correctly based on the top left coordinate of the `<main>` element.

Comment: I never thought that `<main>` wouldn't be supported in the latest version of IE. Now that I know that, I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094276/ie11-is-missing-user-agent-style-for-main-element-display-block). Adding `display: block;` seems to work great.

Comment: It's pretty logical. HTML5 does not allow arbitrary usage of unknown elements, so IE is quite right in not supporting any unknown elements. IE11 is about the same age as Chrome 26 and FF21 which were first to support this very new HTML5 addition. As the element is unknown, it also makes sense that it does not have default styling in the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: The content appears in the `<main>` element but it looks like it is rendering it as an inline element by default, probably because IE doesn't recognize it. It seems like it's all just a side affect of IE's relatively long update cycle. Leaving `<main>` and adding `display: block;` to the CSS gives me the best of both worlds: HTML5 element usage and compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: my God, when will IE be deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

Simple: The `<main>` tag is not supported in IE11.