# Background image won't appear in latest IE

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, background

Here's the CSS. I tried the shorthand that is commented and the long form and none work in IE. I'm even using the latest version of IE. For some reason the image won't display. I tried with multiple images, even just jpgs.

```
    main{
       /* background: url(../images/mosaic-min.png) repeat fixed center center;*/
        background-image: url(../images/mosaic-min.png);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;      
    }
```

I know there is a bug if you don't have a space by the url and the next declaration in the shorthand, but there is a space there. Not even the long form works, though. It is a very large area to cover with the image. Maybe IE automatically prevents this?

Comment: Please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26207036/2565294) It seems like the main tag is not fully supported by ie11

Comment: @Nora Thank you, that solved my issue. Now there is some wonkiness when using the scroll wheel on my mouse, but dragging the scroll bar works fine with the fixed background image. I'm thinking it's just how IE behaves...Anyway if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it for you.

Comment: also, when in doubt about what tags are/are not supported, you can reference [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=html5semantic)